# conda write permission denied error linux

Tags: python, linux, conda

I have a machine at 10.100.100.1. I have mounted it on my local at `/myExternalDrive`

On my local, I have anaconda installed at /anaconda.

```sh
$ which conda 
/anaconda/bin/conda
```

I want to use another disk to maintain my conda environments. Hence:

```
$ cat /anaconda/.condarc
envs_dirs:
  - /myExternalDrive/myConda/envs

pkgs_dirs:
  - /myExternalDrive/myConda/pkgs
```

But when I do

```
$ conda create -n test python=3.6
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed

NoWritablePkgsDirError: No writeable pkgs directories configured.
  - /myExternalDrive/myConda/pkgs
```

This is wierd because I have write access to both `/myExternalDrive/myConda/pkgs` and  `/myExternalDrive/myConda/envs`